# Study names not showing in forest plot (R)

Tags: r, data, visualization, data-analysis

Context: I followed an existing R script to create a forest plot in R using the forest function from the metafor package.

Problem: The plot is showing, however, the study names are not showing on it and I am not sure why.

See data frame here. I want `author` and `year` to show in the forest plot below in place of "Study X": [image: data frame for input into forest plot]

See resulting forest plot here: [image]

Code below:

```
library("here") # detect root directory
library("tidyverse") # data science
library("robumeta")
library("metafor") # for meta-analysis functions
library("dplyr")
library("weightr")
library("knitr")

bio_path <- here("data", "biomarkers.csv") # specify path for dataset 
biomarkers <- read.csv(bio_path) %>% rename("cytokine"="ï..cytokine") %>% select(author:year, cytokine:dep_measure) # load data, rename + reorder col
df <- biomarkers %>% rename(c("ri"="r", "ni"="n")) # rename df and some col for z transformations

df <- escalc(measure="ZCOR", ri=ri, ni=ni, data=df, slab=paste(author, year, sep=", ")) # convert r to z
print(df) # `r`=correlation coefficients; `n`=sample sizes; the new `yi` variable=z score transformation; `vi` variable=corresponding estimated sampling variance.

ifn_y <- df %>% filter(cytokine=="IFN-y" | cytokine=="IFN-y_PHA") %>% mutate(id=1:4) %>% select(id, author:vi)

# print out the data and calculate and print the confidence interval for the amount of heterogeneity (I^2)
res_ifny <- rma(yi, vi, data=ifn_y)  
predict(res_ifny, digits=3, transf=transf.ztor) # convert z back to r
confint(res_ifny) # calc heterogeneity measures with 95% CI  

# visualize the meta analysis with a forest plot
forest(res_ifny, xlim=c(-1.6,1.6), atransf=transf.ztor, at=transf.rtoz(c(-.4,-.2,0,.2,.4,.6)), digits=c(2,1), cex=.8, header = "Author(s), Year", xlab="Correlation coefficient")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried looking at [some examples](https://wviechtb.github.io/metafor/reference/forest.default.html)? You should be able to set the labels for the different studies using the `slab` argument of the `forest` function. Something like this should work:

```
forest(
    res_ifny,
    xlim=c(-1.6,1.6),
    atransf=transf.ztor,
    at=transf.rtoz(c(-.4,-.2,0,.2,.4,.6)),
    digits=c(2,1),
    cex=.8,
    header="Author(s), Year",
    xlab="Correlation coefficient",
    slab=paste(ifn_y$author, ifn_y$year, sep=", ")
)
```

Comment: Thank you! this worked and it would be good to remember to find the information for the function next time. I had been looking at other examples--this was very helpful.